# Covering the sphere by a torus, branched over four points with ramification indices 2,2,3,3?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, covering-spaces

I'm hoping to find a covering map $\Gamma: \Sigma_{g}\rightarrow CP^1$ satisfying following conditions

1. $\Gamma(z_i)=x_i$, where $i=1,2,3,4$
2. $\Gamma(z)=x_i +a_i (z-z_i)^{w_i}+\cdots$, where $w_1=2,w_2=2,w_3=3,w_4=3$ when $z\rightarrow z_i$

The number of preimages of a generic point at $x\in CP^1$ here is 3, from which we could see the genus of $\Sigma_g$ is 1.

There are famous examples on covering the sphere by a torus, branched over four points with ramification indices 2, and  covering the sphere by a torus, branched over three points with ramification indices 3. Any suggestions on generalizing these examples to the problem I want to solve?

Comment: You did not specify the behavior of your map at other preimages of the points $x_1,...,x_4$. Is it because you do not care or because you forgot?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Good point! I should have specified. For my current use, I don't really care about the locations of other preimages.